# Codeigniter Login (Session) Issue

Tags: php, authentication, session, codeigniter-3, vps

My site hosted on the VPS server with PHP version(5.6).
I am facing an issue with login. If I clear browser cache then I can log in.
The issue is with the session is redirecting me back to the login page due to empty session values.
My session values are stored in the database.
My Login Controller code is as follows.

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
    // echo '<br>hiii';
    $username = trim($this->input->post('user_id'));
    $password = trim($this->input->post('password'));
    $where = "(mobile_number = '".$username."' OR email = '".$username."') AND password = '".$password."' AND deactive='0'";
    $where = "(mobile_number = '".$username."' OR email = '".$username."' AND deactive='0')";
    $where_or = array('password' => $password);
    $result = $this->mdgeneraldml->select('*', 'tbl_user', $where, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', $where_or);
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        if ($result[0]['profile_pic'] != '') {
            $profile_img = base_url() . 'img/users/' . $result[0]['profile_pic'];
        } else {
            $profile_img = base_url() . 'img/default_user.png';
        }
    }
}
```

Session Library is loaded in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session', 'email');
```

Comment: can you show the code like how your session is handled and how your setting the session.

Comment: Please check if there is any data in your sessions table in the database? If not - check also that config.php has the correct sessions name listed and that database is your selected option.

Comment: There are many entries in session table

Answer (score 0):

kindly check your codeigniter version, if its the oldest one, try replacing the system directory with your project system directory, it will solve the issue